# text alignment problem in beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing

The text is aligned left even though there is lot of space on right side.
Below is my part of tex file. and the output slide is also attached.

Please suggest what can I do to correct this. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{beaver} %{beetle}%{crane} 
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\title[xyz]{Energy Interactions}
\author[Ramkrishna Sharma]{Ramkrishna Sharma}
\institute[DU]{University of Delhi, INDIA}
\date{September 11, 2014}


\setbeamertemplate{footline}[slide number]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]         % For centering the Heading

\titlegraphic{
    \includegraphics[width=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{figure/cern.jpg}\hspace*{3.35cm}~%
    \includegraphics[width=2cm,keepaspectratio]{figure/logo_du.jpeg}\hspace*{2.75cm}~%
    \includegraphics[width=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{figure/cmsLogo.jpeg}
}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\inserttotalframenumber}{\pageref{lastslide}}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Table of contents}\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[shrink=20]\frametitle{Motivation}
\begin{block}{Higgs boson Found!!!}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Discovery of Higgs boson anounced on 4 July 2012.
    \end{itemize}
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Queries}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item But, now the question about Higgs boson split into two queries\footfullcite{Massironi:2014fma}:
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Is this the only Higgs boson present in Nature?
        \item Is it really doing {\bf the Higgs boson} job?
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Answer: Mainly three roads}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item keep searching for scalar outside of m=125GeV\footfullcite{Chatrchyan:2013yoa},
    \item measure with high precision the properties of the 125GeV boson\footfullcite{CMS:2014ega}, and
    \item measure the electroweak vector boson interactions.
    \end{itemize}
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's the default behavior and looks OK to me. If you just remove the bibliography items and push the answer block to another slide it's going to be even better.

Comment: @percusse: Is there any way by which the reference can utilize the full horizontal line.

Comment: Use `\footnote[frame]{your references}`. This forces footnotes to be shown at the bottom of the frame. (Beamer Guide §12.12)